# How to dismiss AlertDialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I created AlertDialog that contains 4 buttons

```
OptionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        OptionDialog.setTitle("Options");
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.options, null, false);
        background = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bkgSpinnerLabel);
        SoundVib = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.SoundVibSpinnerLabel);
        
        OptionDialog.setView(v);
        OptionDialog.setCancelable(true);
        OptionDialog.setNeutralButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    }
                });
        background.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SetBackground();
             // here I want to dismiss it after SetBackground() method 
            }
        });
        

        SoundVib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent soundVibIntent = new Intent(SebhaActivity.this, EditPreferences.class);
                startActivity(soundVibIntent);
            }
        });
        
        OptionDialog.show();
```

I want to dismiss it after SetBackground() method, how can I do this?

Comment: Please, use java naming conventions: methods and variable names should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: use dialog.dismiss(); after SetBackground();

Comment: @DaanGeurts - there is no any `dismiss()` method from `AlertDialog.Builder` Class.

Comment: @user370305 right, i've missed that one, your answer should work

Comment: OptionDialog.setView(null);

Comment: The simplest way I have found to dismiss the AlertDialog is to add

    Navigator.pop(context);

To my buttons' onPressed: property.  This particularly useful when keeping things very simple by doing everything in line.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Actually there is no any `cancel()` or `dismiss()` method from AlertDialog.Builder Class.

So Instead of `AlertDialog.Builder optionDialog` use `AlertDialog` instance.

Like,

```
AlertDialog optionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

Now, Just call  `optionDialog.dismiss();`

```
background.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SetBackground();
        // here I want to dismiss it after SetBackground() method 
        optionDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: Really nice, the part important is : "NOT CREATE A ( AlertDialog.Builder OptionDialog  = AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); )  if not create (AlertDialog OptionDialog =new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); ) after you can calls .dismiss(); so great, thanks !!!!!

Comment: A note here is that `OptionDialog` needs to be visible to the onclick listerner in the snippet above.  One way to do to this is to declare the `AlertDialog` as a member variable in the parent activity class.

Comment: should I do `optionDialog = null` after dismissing it to avoid memory leak?

Answer (score 65):

I think there's a simpler solution: Just use the `DialogInterface` argument that is passed to the `onClick` method.

```
AlertDialog.Builder db = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        db.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int arg1) {
                db.cancel();
                //here db.cancel will dismiss the builder

            };  
        });
```

See, for example, http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example.

Comment: `d.dismiss();` worked for me, and Yes, this one is more simple and native to AlertDialog

Comment: I believe this is still the correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   AlertDialog OptionDialog = builder.create();
  background.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SetBackground();
       OptionDialog .dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this before and not worked for me until I used the code that is in the accepted answer.

Comment: ok i missed thi line  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); now edit the answer...

Comment: @Android_coder what to do when inside a fragment? `this` will be null.

Answer (score 6):

To dismiss or cancel AlertDialog.Builder

```
dialog.setNegativeButton("إلغاء", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

you call dismiss() on the dialog interface

Answer (score 2):

Here is How I close my alertDialog

```
lv_three.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                GetTalebeDataUser clickedObj = (GetTalebeDataUser) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                alertDialog.setTitle(clickedObj.getAd());
                alertDialog.setMessage("Öğrenci Bilgileri Güncelle?");
                alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info);
                // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // User pressed YES button. Write Logic Here
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("İptal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //alertDialog.
                        alertDialog.setCancelable(true); // HERE

                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of closing an alert dialog.

Option 1:

`AlertDialog#create().dismiss();`

Option 2:

`The DialogInterface#dismiss();`

Out of the box, the framework calls `DialogInterface#dismiss();` when you define event listeners for the buttons:

1. `AlertDialog#setNegativeButton();`
2. `AlertDialog#setPositiveButton();`
3. `AlertDialog#setNeutralButton();`

for the Alert dialog.

Answer (score 1):

With Kotlin:

```
fun Activity.showDialog() {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setMessage(R.string.message_id)
        .setPositiveButton(
            R.string.confirm_action_text_id
        ) { dialogInterface, _ ->
            dialogInterface.dismiss()
            SignUpActivity.start(this)
        }
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel) { _, _ -> }
    builder.create().show()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just set the view as null that will close the AlertDialog simple.